# using a literal $ in a grep search

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to use a literal $ as an end anchor for a search using grep. The entire problem is search for line(s) in a file that start with At and ends with a literal $. I have tried several variations of the code I think will work and get no results even though there should be.
`grep '\<At[a-zA-z]\{1,\}\$\>' test.txt`

Any suggestions would be appreciated and I am a first year student of Linux so forgive me if I am missing something simple. Thank you

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/131522/9232

Answer (score 2):

```
grep '\<At[a-zA-z]\{1,\}[$]\>' test.txt
```

To avoid playing shell escaping games, put the $ inside a character class.

Comment: awesome, I got it to work but I modified it a bit so the option of no character between the At and $ would work. grep '\<At[a-zA-Z]\{0,\}'[$]$ test.txt. Thanks everyone!